# how to have conditional required fields through hook_form_alter?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

Here is basically what I'm trying to do.
If the draft field is present I would like to make the name field not required.

```
if($form_state['values']['field_draft']['und'][0]['value']){
  $form['field_name']['und']['#required'] = FALSE; }
```

Is this even possible? I tried after_build but it doesn't work.  If not, is there a better way to add draft functionality through hook_form_alter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7, I would use the following code.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'your_form_id':
      $lang = $form['name_field']['#language'];//get field language
      if(isset($form_state['values']['field_draft'][$lang][0]['value'])){
        $form['name_field'][$lang][0]['value']['#required'] = FALSE;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Note: Never use **und** try to get the language for multilingual sites. If site is not multilingual, then best to use the constant **LANGUAGE_NONE** and not the string `'und'`.

Comment: I think "never" is a bit strong. If I'm building a website that I know will never need internationalization and I'm writing code that will only ever be used on that specific site then it's perfectly acceptable to use 'und' and save some lines of code.

Comment: ofcourse if the site is multilingual sites then need to get the language. If site is not multilingual then you can use the constant **LANGUAGE_NONE** and not the string 'und'.

Comment: Language none is defined as: define('LANGUAGE_NONE', 'und'). I'm happy to assume that this definition will not change so it's less typing to put 'und' than LANGUAGE_NONE.

Comment: Still very much not advisable to use 'und' instead of LANGUAGE_NONE, even though it is unlikely to change. It doesn't save you many keystrokes (about half a second worth of typing) to future proof yourself. Laziness can sometimes come back to bite you on the butt.

Comment: Your IDE will suggest the constant name in a quater second, so LANGUAGE_NONE is for the laziest one.

Comment: @I agree with @rooby, here. There is a reason we use a constant, and not directly the value of the constant. And yes, there is nothing that stops developers from changing the value of a constant; it happened before, and it can happen again.

Answer (score 0):

please try it in hook_form_alter

```
$form['field_name']['#required'] = isset($form_state['values']['field_draft'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The OP is trying to set the property of a form element for a field basing on the value assigned to another field. The node title is not handled by the field API.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential explanation with the code. Now the answer seems bad (an answer, true, just bad one, as @kiamlaluno said), but maybe the logic behind it was decent, and could be usable?